# querying/retrieving objects stored in a list (python 3.3)

Tags: python, list, class, object, instance

For my Introduction to Python assignment I created instances of classes, stored in lists. I can print or delete them by their position in the list, but really, I need to be able to query individual attributes, like filter out only the available ones, change their availability, or display the cost,  of each of the objects. I'll attach some of the code:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self,plateno,kml,dailycost,weeklycost,weekendcost):            #attributes common to all vehicles
        self.plateno=plateno
        self.kml=kml
        self.dailycost=dailycost
        self.weeklycost=weeklycost
        self.weekendcost=weekendcost
        self.avail=True

#   methods

    def __str__(self):b
        return "Vehicle Plate Number: {0}, km/l: {1}, daily: {2},weekly: {3}, weekend: {4}".format(self.plateno, self.kml, self.dailycost, self.weeklycost, self.weekendcost)

    def __del__(self):
        return "Vehicle deleted: {0}".format(self.plateno)



class Cvn(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self,plateno,kml,bedno,dailycost,weeklycost,weekendcost):
        Vehicle.__init__(self,plateno,kml,dailycost, weeklycost, weekendcost)
        self.bedno=bedno

    def __str__(self):
        return "Caravan: Plate Number: {0}, km/l: {1}, number of beds: {2}, daily: {3},weekly: {4}, weekend: {5}, Available? {6}".format(self.plateno, self.kml, self.bedno, self.dailycost, self.weeklycost, self.weekendcost, self.avail)


#   I N S T A N C E S

  #   C A R A V A N S   Class:Cvn
  #   (self,plateno,kml,bedno,dailycost,weeklycost,weekendcost)

#------------------
#caravanheaders=["Km/l","Number of beds","Plate number","Daily cost","Weekly cost","Weekend cost"]
cvn1=[12,4,"11-D-144",50,350,200]
cvn2=[10,6,"10-D-965",50,365,285]         #values as per Caravan table
cvn3=[11,4,"12-C-143",50,350,200]
cvn4=[15,2,"131-G-111",50,250,185]

cvnslist=[cvn1,cvn2,cvn3,cvn4]    #this list contains 4 variables, each representing a list, as above
cvns=[]                           #this is going to be the list of lists

for i in cvnslist:          #this loop creates a list of lists 'cvns'
     cvns.append(i)
print("")
print(cvns)             #the list of lists

cvninstances=[]
for i in range(len(cvns)):
    cvninstances.append(Cvn(cvns[i][2],cvns[i][0],cvns[i][1],cvns[i][3],cvns[i][4],cvns[i][5]))
    vehlist.append(Cvn(cvns[i][2],cvns[i][0],cvns[i][1],cvns[i][3],cvns[i][4],cvns[i][5]))

#    print(cvninstances)  #this shows just that there are objects, but not their attibutes
#for i in cvninstances:
#    print(i)
print("")

for i in vehlist:
    print("On Vehicles List: ",i)
print("")
print("Initial fleet displayed.")
print("")

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

most of the answers to similar questions on here are at a much more advanced level, unfortunately for me!

Comment: Do you know how to get an attribute of an instance?

Comment: I know for an object that I created as e.g. Student1=Student("Mary"), I can get the name Mary by calling Student1.name (Class being Student(self,name))...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I think that @sweeneyrod got the point : it also seems to me that your problem is to access an attribute of an instance, which can be done as :

```
instance.attribute
```

If this is the case, please read again : http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects

Something else, this piece of code can be rewritten in a more elegant fashion :

```
cvninstances.append(Cvn(cvns[i][2],cvns[i][0],cvns[i][1],cvns[i][3],cvns[i][4],cvns[i][5]))
```

I would first reorder your cvn_i list so that arguments are in the same order as Cvn __init__ method then write it as :

```
cvninstances.append(Cvn(*cvns[i]))
```

* has the following meaning : "take all the item in cvns[i] and use them as arguments to instantiate a Cvn"

(Maybe that's too of an "advanced level" - to use your own word - but I think this is definitely a pattern that you'll have to know ;))

---

[Added]

Cf comments, to filter, use list comprehension :

```
[veh for veh in vehlist if veh.avail==True]
```

which can be written like this in a shorter way (cause veh.avail is intended to contain a boolean) :

```
[veh for veh in vehlist if veh.avail]
```

If you are used to database queries, this is - conceptually - very similar :)

[/Added]

Comment: Thanks for this, i've used the instance.attribute before, but in this case I'm not sure how to access the instance, other than by its position in the list. If I wanted to list all for which avail=True, would I have to go through a loop checking each one and adding them to a new list, or is there a quicker way? I'm more used to very basic database queries than actual programming, so this is a steep learning curve for me!

Comment: In fact, you're doing both when writing something like [veh for veh in vehlist if veh.avail==True]. You're both filtering and implicitely creating a new list that will store the results. For info, I find comprehension list more natural cause it's almost the same thing that you could write in Math when working with sets (and after all 'comprehension' is named the same as a set theory axiom :p)

Comment: [veh for veh in vehlist if veh.avail==True] could be reduced to [veh for veh in vehlist if veh.avail]. But I prefered to write explicitely the ==True clause so that it is clearer for you ;)

Comment: I'll have a go at that one, thank you. Natural, explicit and clear are definitely still my priorities, Thanks!

Comment: @backtoschool : if it helped, please mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You will find [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) useful here:

> `filter(function, iterable)`: Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If iterable is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list. If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

You a can create arbitrary functions for filtering using `lambda`:

```
matches = filter(lambda x: x.attr == val, obj_list)
```

This will give you a list of all object instances for which the attribute `attr` has the value `val`. If you want multiple possible values, e.g. a list of possible `vals`:

```
lambda x: x.attr in vals
```

You can also do this using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which are very common in Python:

```
matches = [i for i in obj_list if i.attr == val]
```

Comment: Definitely it is a good point but it appears to me that backtoschool is learning Python, so using comprehension list will be a more "natural" way to do it : something like : [item for item in lst if item.attr=val]